# How to customize which patterns bash treats as "hidden" files/directories

Tags: bash, configuration, hidden-files

In Unix systems, files and directories that begin with `.` are "hidden". Microsoft Office creates temporary files that begin with `~$`, such as `~$Unnamed_document.docx`. I would like to make `bash` – and especially `ls` – treat these files as hidden files, too. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: This might help: `man ls | grep hide`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define this alias:

```
alias ls=ls --hide='~$*'
```

Files starting with `~$` will be hidden. Use `ls -a` to show the hidden files.